# How to write a Trigger on Knowledge Base Article?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I need to create a Trigger on Knowledge Base Article, but it may seem impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Classic SF or Lighting? Knowledge in both seems to work differently, see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_compare_classic_lightning.htm&type=5.

I don't have an org with Knowledge enabled handy, can't check...

You might not be able to put a trigger on the generic `KnowledgeArticleVersion` but should be possible to do it on your custom `FAQ__kav` or what have you. See also https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_knowledge_considerations.htm and https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jVKGAA2